# Dynamic React-Router 1.0.0-rc3

Tags: reactjs, react-router

> Regardless of what I have read from the folks at react-router, I
>   prefer my app's router have dynamic data, and I have been successful
>   in doing it, with one caveat: I cannot loop recursively for child
>   routes.

**Here is a working dynamic react-router:**

```
export default class Index extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      navItems: [] };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    NavMenuAPI.getAll()
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.setState({ navItems: data });
      });
  }
```

---

```
  fetchMenuSystem(data) {
    const routes = [];
    data.map(function(route) {
      let routePaths = [];
      let component = {};
      if (route.linkTo === '/') {
        const pageApp = route.title.replace(/ /g, '-').toLocaleLowerCase();
        component = require('./components/pages/' + pageApp);
      } else {
        const pageApp = route.title.replace(/ /g, '-').toLocaleLowerCase();
        component = require('./components/pages/' + pageApp);
      }
      if (route.paths === undefined) {
        routePaths.push(route.linkTo);
      } else {
        routePaths = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(route.paths));
      }

      routePaths.map(function(path) {
        const props = { key: path, path, component };
        // Static `onEnter` is defined on
        // component, we should pass it to route props
        // if (component.onEnter) props.onEnter = component.onEnter;
        routes.push(<Route { ...props } />);
      });

      //////////////////////////////////////////////
      //  PROBLEM !!!!!!!!!! 
      // if (route.childNodes !== undefined) {
      //  this.fetchMenuSystem(route.childNodes);
      // }
    });
    return routes;
  }
```

---

```
  fetchRoutes() {
    const data = this.state.navItems;
    const result = this.fetchMenuSystem(data);
    return (
      <Route component={ require('./components/APP') }>
        { result }
        <Route path="*" component={ require('./components/pages/not-found') }/>
      </Route>
    );
  }
```

---

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.navItems.length === 0) return <div>Loading ...</div>;
    const routerProps = {
      routes: this.fetchRoutes(),
      history: createHistory({
        queryKey: false
      }),
      createElement: (component, props) => {
        return React.createElement(component, { ...props });
      }
    };
    return (
      <Router { ...routerProps } />
    );
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('reactRoot'));
```

As I said, this works, however, only for the first level, when I try to recursively loop through for any childNodes, I receive the error:

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchMenuSystem' of undefined**

I tried to bind the call to the fetch function and bind the mapping, none of which worked.

I would greatly appreciate assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved this. The problem lied with the routes state & the 'this' keyword.

**Here are the changes:**

```
export default class Index extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      navItems: [],
      routes: []
    };
  }

      ................

  fetchMenuSystem(data) {
    const currRoutesState = this.state.routes;
    const self = this;
    data.map(function(route) {

      ................

      routePaths.map(function(path) {
      ................
        currRoutesState.push(<Route { ...props } />);
      });

      if (route.childNodes !== undefined) {
        self.fetchMenuSystem(route.childNodes);
      }
    });
    return currRoutesState;
  }

      ................
```

}

---

> **Final thoughts if you plan on using this:**
>
> **[Re: npm install --save history]**
>
> **I had to opt for 100% client side routing, 
>   (not isomorphic/universal) so in my imports ....**

```
  import createHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory'; 
  //  import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
```